# Plsql Procedure in invalid state

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have created following procedure:

```
 create or replace function getDepartmentById(name varchar2)
  return number
  is v_dep number(10)
  begin
  --the sql statement is totally fine
 select deptno into v_dep from dept where dname = name;
  end;
/
```

but when I call

```
 select getDepartmentById('SALES') into dep from dual;
```

I get this error message

```
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 20, column 14:
PL/SQL: ORA-06575: Package or function GETDEPARTMENTBYID is in an invalid state
ORA-06550: line 20, column 7:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

Comment: You wrote in your question: _I have created following procedure_ You have created a stored ___function___ and not a stored procedure. A stored function needs a **return** statement. The code in your question does not have a **return** statement.

Comment: Please refer to [8.5.1 Additional Parts for Functions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/lnpls/plsql-subprograms.html#GUID-5E23F601-5194-4F40-823B-C1BD12B9248C) from _Database PL/SQL Language Reference_ chapter 8 [_PL/SQL Subprograms_] which is part of Oracle dicumentation for 18c database.

Comment: add a semi-colon after `v_dep number(10)`

Comment: What development tools do you use for PL/SQL? If you can't view compilation errors then you are in for a hard time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a return value for the function. It goes like this :

```
CREATE OR replace FUNCTION Getdepartmentbyid(name VARCHAR2) 
RETURN NUMBER 
IS 
  v_dep NUMBER(10); 
BEGIN 
    --the sql statement is totally fine 
    SELECT deptno 
    INTO   v_dep 
    FROM   dept 
    WHERE  dname = name; 

    RETURN v_dep; 
END;
```

You can not use a `INTO` in your select statement. You should call the function like this.

```
select getDepartmentById('SALES') from dual;
```

Comment: okay that worked, but how can I store the value from  getDepartmentById('SALES') in a variable in anothe procedure?

Comment: In another procedure you should declare a variable then assign it to your function. l_dept_no number(10) , l_dept_no :=getDepartmentById('SALES');